# What happens if you buy vehicles off of GTAV’s ifruit app

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Sooo it just occurred to me that I can customize/make vehicles off the ifruit app. It gave a hefty price and I’m wondering does it take it out of my real life bank account or my gta V bank account? PLEASE TELL ME THE TRUTH IM WORRIED

Answer (score 3):

It takes it out of your GTA V bank account.